# How do I directly read and write database files in vb2008?

Tags: database, vb.net

How do I read and write a file using a file format which is readable by a database server, in vb2008?

I have very little experience working with databases, and I can't seem to find any tutorials which don't involve some type of server as a middle-man.

Comment: By "readable by database server" do you mean works with SQL server import tools?  Such as DTS or SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really going to depend on which type of database files you are working with.  If you have an Access Database file, you can open a connection to the database with the following code.

```
Dim DBConn as New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyDBFile.mdb;")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a server, use SQLite.  There are .NET bindings that work quite nicely.

Reading and writing the raw database files would be an immense undertaking -- if you have to ask how to do it, you shouldn't.  It requires so much work that it's not even worth considering for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

In general, most database-aware software writes to the database using a software library adapter.  Like [ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odbc).

What you might be looking for is the file format that a bulk loader can understand.  Something like [this](http://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2005/fall/23500-1/mysql-load.html) (MySQL example).